# Stationary VS. limiting probability

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, probability-limit-theorems, stationary-processes

I'm just wondering what the difference between stationary probability and limiting probability is.

And, if any of you know: What does it mean that some elements exist and some elements doesn't, when $\lim_{k \to \infty} \mathbf{P}^{(k)}$. Here, $\mathbf{P}$ is transition probability matrix describing a descrete-time Markov chain.

I'd really appreciate some advice!

Comment: You should look at [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9325/equilibrium-distribution-steady-state-distribution-stationary-distribution-and).

Comment: Thank you, @Ritz! I actually saw the question before I asked mine, since I thought stationary and limiting probabilities were a bit different than stationary and limiting _distributions_, but now I guess they're not :)

Comment: Let's say the state space of our Markov chain is $S$. Then, $p(i), ~ i \in S$ is a specific stationary probability and $p(\cdot)$ (so for all states in $S$) is the stationary distribution. In essence the distribution describes all stationary probabilities. Hope this clarifies it for you.

Comment: Ah, that clarifies it! Thank you so much.