# Expected Value and Variance of a Markov Chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Say I have a transition matrix $Q = \begin{bmatrix}
    1-p       & p \\
    p       & 1-p 
\end{bmatrix}$ where $0 < p < 1$ for a two state system with states $-1$ and $1.$ Define $X_i$ to be the value of the markov chain at time $i$ (so either $-1$ or $1$). If $\bar{X_i} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n X_i$ what is the $\mathbb{E}[\bar{X_i}]$ and $Var[\bar{X_i}]$?

I've started off by tackling $\mathbb{E}[\bar{X_i}]$ but it seems to me that this answer depends on whether $n$ is even or odd. Note since this is a Markov chain there is not pairwise independence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2113485/understanding-invariant-and-stationary-distributions-for-markov-chains/2113593#2113593) the stationary probabilities of such a Markov chain are calculated for the state transition matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}
p&1-p\\
1-q&q
\end{bmatrix}.$$ If $p=q>0$ then the  $n^{th}$ power of the state transition probability tends quite fast to

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\frac12&\frac12\\
\frac12&\frac12
\end{bmatrix}.$$

So, for $p=q$ the stationary probabilities are both $\frac12$.

So, on the long run $1$ and $-1$ appears with the same probability. The expectation is then $0$. As far as the variance, we have $1^2\frac12+(-1)^2\frac12$=1.